recording audio and playing sound not working in ios in react native
`I am creating an app and wants a need where i have to record user audio and same time have to play sone sound kind of background music. After providing all permissions it is working in android but in ios while recording sound not playing. I am using react-native-sound for sound and react-native-audio-record for recording. Please find attached the ios file AppDelegate.mm that contains the permissions
`
`#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = @"ShaaleCLI";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                                   withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                                         error:nil];
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  return [self getBundleURL];
}

- (NSURL *)getBundleURL
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end`

How to fix this issue for ios, what are the different options to solve it`
